# Android: как сделать кастомный диалог поверх экрана приложения?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-ui

Хочу добавить в своё приложение пошаговое руководство типа Quick Start. Хочу сделать примерно так:

[image: скриншот]

То есть окно с руководством:

1. Показывается поверх экрана приложения не на весь экран.
2. Содержит заголовок, область контента с картинкой и текстом и кнопки "Вперёд" и "Назад". На первом шаге есть только кнопка "Вперёд", на последнем экране вместо кнопки "Вперёд" кнопка "Закончить".
3. При нажатии кнопки "Назад" на смартфоне или при касании экрана вне этого окна оно закрывается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такое пошаговое руководство наиболее простым способом?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - сделать кастомную разметку и показывать диалог с ней. Для начала стоит определить что именно вам нужно. Судя по скриншоту у вас будет все просто, и если вы создавали разметку в xml то я думаю проблем быть не должно. Дальше я приведу пример. Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingLeft="20dp"
              android:paddingRight="20dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

и дальше мы вызываем обычный Alert но крепим к нему макет:

```
// create an alert builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Name");
// set the custom layout
final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
builder.setView(customLayout);
// add a button
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // send data from the AlertDialog to the Activity
    EditText editText = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    sendDialogDataToActivity(editText.getText().toString());
}
});
// create and show the alert dialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

есть так же и вариант с использованием Dialog():

```
// custom dialog
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
dialog.setTitle("Title...");

// set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
dialog.dismiss();
}
});
dialog.show();
```

[туториал 1](https://suragch.medium.com/creating-a-custom-alertdialog-bae919d2efa5), [туториал 2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-custom-dialog-in-android) и [туториал 3](https://mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/). Вашей задачей по факту будет только создание xml с разметкой которую вы привели в вопросе, а дальше уже по аналогии с активностью все элементы подключаете и добавляете обработку кликов.